# Twilio webhook sms response format

Tags: json, sms, twilio, webhooks

I'm using Twilio with my app and I have sms webhooks with my SMS numbers configured with URL.
Everything is working except that Twilio send me an error in logs for each requests.
I suppose that the response from my app is not well formated but I can't find on documentation how to format using JSON.

Can someone help me ? :)

Thanks,
Gabriel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you return a webhook message to Twilio, you need to make sure it's valid [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), which in essence is just a set of XML verbs Twilio uses.

If you're responding to an SMS message for example, you would return TwiML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Thanks for getting in touch, I'll call you later</Message>
</Response>
```

You can test the code above by changing the configuration of your number to point to [this url](http://twimlbin.com/external/5dc7eab9a2239f4e94d5e00bb9a8dcd0) and you should stop seeing the errors.

If you generating the TwiML yourself, you need to make sure that the page's MIME type is text/xml.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've not configured a TwiML app but only an URL. Is this the same ? Can I return only XML, not JSON ?

Comment: Yeah, they end up being the same. So having a URL only is fine, but you need to make sure you return XML as per https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml to get the best results