# Twilio Error - 12200 - Schema validation warning - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio-api

I have a webHook receiver that listens to Twilio POST. Scenario: SMS message is sent to my Twilio number, Twilio does POST to the webHook receiver, webHook processes the request (works as expected) and finally WebHook returns back a response object Twilio.TwiML.MessagingResponse. The problem is I'm receiving a warning in the Twilio Debugger with message "Content is not allowed in prolog." The warning shows in the REQUEST section of the Request Inspector and didn't know what to do about it.
[screenshot of error/warn message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7gXH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for looking into this. Answer by @marcos-placona in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798818/1981369) made me revisit the webHook return type. Sure enough the return type needs to be a TwiML formatted XML. That led to the discovery of the overloaded ToString() extension method.

---

public string ToString([System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions formattingOptions = System.Xml.Linq.SaveOptions.None])
    Member of Twilio.TwiML.TwiML

Summary:
Generate XML string from TwiML object

Parameters:
formattingOptions: Change generated string format.

---

for this to work, [System.Xml.Linq] needs to be referenced.

```
using Twilio.TwiML;

var twilioResponse = new MessagingResponse();
var message = new Twilio.TwiML.Messaging.Message("Thanks for your response."); 
twilioResponse.Append(message);
return twilioResponse.ToString();
```

Hope this helps someone.