# Twilio inbound SMS using webhooks and Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sms, twilio

I have setup SMS on Twilio and can receive an SMS via webhooks. I can manipulate the form data to do what I want however every inbound SMS message throws an error on Twilio's dashboard. It's looking for some response. Right now I'm just dumping the form to a text file while testing.

```
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<head>
<Response>   
</Response>
    <cfdump
        var="#form#"
        label="HTTP Body" output="C:/webhook-sms.txt"
        />
</head>
</html>
```

The error is: MESSAGE
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Warning - 12200
Schema validation warning
The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema. Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem.

What do I need to respond to Twilio with?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gary

Comment: Maybe try getting rid of the `<!doctype html>` and ensuring the content type is text/xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792254/twilio-webhook-sms-response-format#36798818

Comment: You might also want to get rid of the html and head elements... that’s html, and probably not what they are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio expects a content type of `text/xml` and also expects the first line of the response to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

If your response has one or more empty lines before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` you're still going to get an error.

What I ended up doing, was with an Application.cfm something like this:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" showdebugoutput="false" requesttimeout="30" />
<cfheader name="content-type" value="text/xml" />
<!--- // more code --->
```

and endpoint files which start with the first line like this:

```
<cfoutput><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?></cfoutput>
<!--- // more code --->
```

And make sure you send back valid TwiML (Twilio's XML) (no HTML).

Comment: The joys of xml responses.  Is it possible use a cfc instead of a cfm, to avoid the issues with white space, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everybody. My final test code looked like this:

```
    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" showdebugoutput="false" requesttimeout="30" />
<cfheader name="content-type" value="text/xml" />
<cfoutput><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Message>Thanks for getting in touch, I'll call you later</Message>
</Response></cfoutput>
```